# Could not find destination file during file copy

Tags: c#, .net, file-copying

We've seen this issue described elsewhere when it relates to the source file, but not the destination file.

We're trying to copy a 70MB file from a local path on the source server to a share on the destination server. The entire process is iterating over many files on the main thread and other files have successfully copied before we see the issue.  However, we occasionally see this error:

```
Could not find file 'DestinationFileFullPath'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
```

I need to emphasize this point: the error refers to the destination file name, not the source. And we're certain that we haven't mixed up the variables. This is the code:

```
ConsoleLog(String.Format("Copying file from {0} to {1}", source, dest));
File.Copy(source, dest);
```

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Does destination PATH exist?

Comment: Are you missing the file extension?

Comment: You can first give a check if Destination exist then only try to copy.

Comment: You are passing the name of a file path _variable_ (`DestinationFileFullPath`) rather then the file path?

Comment: You can copy your destination path from console to explorer and check it

Comment: I would check your network. Maybe because of package-loss the server is not available sometimes?

Comment: To answer:  1) destination path does exist, otherwise earlier file copies in the loop would fail.  2) both source and destination are full paths inc file name and extension.

Comment: @ms10 I am having the exact same issue when copying lots of files from a remote server to a local machine, C# complains about not finding the destination file, even though the destination folder exists and on a second try it often succeeds. I suspect that the network is faulty, but the error message is confusing.
Did you find more about it?

Answer (score 1):

A possibility for anyone who might end up on this thread:

You will get this error in both File.Move and File.Copy if the 'source' and 'destination' arguments are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can also see this message if the destination file name (excluding any extension) is a reserved DOS name: CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1-9, LPT1-9.